# How to start an Android project using QT 5?

Tags: android, qt, apk

I'm starting Qt programming for android but cannot compile a project as android! How can I start an Android project using Qt Studio?

I started QT Studio and created a new project. in the project info:

"**Supported Platform:** Desktop Android"

- But I cannot compile an APK file. How this works?
- Is Qt for Visual Studio simpler to use?(I'm familar with it)

Comment: Everything you need to get started is listed here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html

Answer (score 0):

What you meant by starting an android project? If you are trying to compile existing project to android or If you are trying to develop cross platform application it's OK to use Qt for Android but If your application solely target to android only think 100 times before go for Qt.

These links might help you to getting start with Qt for android.

[Getting Started with Qt for Android](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html)

[Build and deploy Qt apps to Android using Qt 5.1 on Windows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html) (bit old but build steps are same)

Comment: I want to start deploying apps for android and probably IOS and Windows phone in the future. Do you mean Qt is a bad choice for android development? Is it slower than using pure C++? It seems ok

Comment: There is no direct yes no answer for choosing right platform. I just want you to emphasis that Using Qt for android is not worth if you are only gonna deploy it for Android. As you said you are planning to cross compile it to several other platforms, Qt is a grate choice.  From my experience Qt for android is quite fast, but It build size it quite bigger than normal Android SDK.